# JPDF for uniform-distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution, correlation

you are given that the joint distribution of X and Y is uniform on the region defined by the conditions: $0<x<1$, $x<y<x+1$. Find the correlation coefficient of X and Y

My problem with this question is getting the area of the jpdf.I thought it would be just one, but that didn't work. Can anyone help me with this part of the question? Don't bother with actually integrating it, I can do that easily.

Comment: The "area" is indeed one. Which part of your approach didn't work? Please `edit` to improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Comment: Joint pdf is just $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\text{area of given region}}\mathbf1_{0<x<1,x<y<x+1}=\mathbf1_{0<x<1,x<y<x+1}$, where $\mathbf1$ is an indicator function.